# $_SESSION variable not 'unsetting'

Tags: php, session, unset

The following is occurring:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['myvar'] = 'something';

class SessionControl
{
    public function unsetSessionVar($varName)
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION))
        {
            session_start();
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION[$varName]))
        {
            unset($_SESSION[$varName])
        }
        echo 'TEST 1: [' . $_SESSION[$varName] . ']';
     }
}
$SesContr = new SessionControl();
$SesContr->unsetSessionVar('myvar');
echo "TEST 2: [" . $_SESSION['myvar'] . ']';
```

Which produces:

```
TEST 1: []

TEST 2: [something]
```

What's happening here?

Comment: For me it's working properly. What web server do you use on which OS? Restarting it may help?

Comment: This code works on my server as expected - variable unsets. Considering that you have a syntax error, may be you posted not the original code?

Comment: first things first. you are missing a semi-colon when unsetting

Comment: ya it works correctly for me too. When you unset. Apache gives an error saying undefined index 'myvar' (which means that it did got unset). If I don't unset, I see **something** in both tests. Another thing is that I would suggest not to unset variables for ending sessions. Use `session_destroy()`.

Comment: Also, you don't need `session_start()` in there twice - once at the top of your file is plenty.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should give you syntex error.. you have missed ";"behind unset statement.it should be like this..

```
unset($_SESSION[$varName]);
```

run it if it may solve your problem.

Comment: is this necessary to set semi-column in a single line statement?? i don't think so

Comment: any statement excepting loop and if statements.. we need to put ; .. it is necessary